# Download, Update, Compile and publish Android source code on Windows

Tags: android, compilation, root

Hey Guys,
 I want to do a nice test to the Android OS. I would like to flash my rooted Android device with my own android OS version. I am doing so because I want to change some system app and kernel framework to act differently.

So I know I can download the source code with git, but can I open it with Eclipse? how do I compile it, and the most important question, how do I flash it back (with the changes) to the device?

I need to do it on Windows...I know it suppose to run on Mac\Linux, any free solution?

Thanks
 M

Answer (score 2):

A free solution, if there aren't any windows tools. Is simply to download a Linux distribution, and use that. As linux is free :)
I'd recommend Wubuntu, You can install it from inside windows and reboot straight into it, no real hassle and a nice Android Dev environment :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably should ask the people over at [xda-developers forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) to see if there is a windows tool set that they recommend for Android OS development.